# Communicate with my PHP API securely from ReactJS Axios

Tags: php, reactjs, api, axios, jwt

I’m wondering how we can make a secure call to our backend API. I created a form that sends the data to my backend API and which it does the processing. But what my question is that, even If I use JWT still the the Bearer token is visible in Header and can be stolen to make request with Postman or some-other applications. Is there any other way to communicate to my API securely. And kindly ask you to give solutions or articles or documentations linking to it. Or actually the following method is secure? Because there is no login form, it’s just a normal registration form for an event. I just need to store the data but communicate with my API securely from ReactJS.

Comment: Use HTTPS and encrypt your JWT token. If you wish to ensure that only _your_ website makes request to API, I think there is no reliable way to ensure that

Comment: _"the Bearer token is visible in Header and can be stolen to make request with Postman or some-other applications."_ - and the actual tragedy in that would be what, exactly?